# "1 hidden accounts"

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, plurals, hidden-communities

I know, it's a pluralization bug... but this one isn't too obscure, so I think I can report it without fear of being lynched:

[image]

When I go to my profile page, I see the above.

One fixes needed.

Comment: Best solution is to just drop the second "accounts" word so it just says "1 hidden" - we don't really need to say accounts twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed and will be with you in the next build.

So happy we have localization stuff now that make these trivial to fix.

Comment: No more dead users?

Comment: @Emrakul - the big S has been refactored into many small ones.