# The '1 hidden accounts' issue has come up again

Tags: bug, profile-page, plurals, hidden-communities, regression

This is essentially the same question as [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260835/1-hidden-accounts) one, which says that the 'Accounts' section under Summary has a mistake with the pluralization, as in the screenshot below:

[image: picture]

The reason I'm posting this as a new question is that the old one is from over seven years ago, and is marked as status-completed. The answer to the question also suggests that it has been 'fixed,' or at least that it would be soon. (This is my first post on Meta, so sorry if I've done this incorrectly!)

I notice that the display of the Accounts section has changed since the old post, so perhaps the corrected version was lost during various reconfigurations/redesigns. Or maybe the change was never implemented for whatever reason.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: It was fixed, but oddly enough, many of that specific developer bug fixes has been reverted, rolled back, or just disappeared into the void. Only those who did/doing that can know why though, and stop it from happening. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars - huh. So the correction _was_ made, but it was eventually lost?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it worked fine for a while. That said, the page design was changed over time, things moved, and that's when the fix was gone, probably. Sadly, it happens a lot.